# Visual Studio debugging and running server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I have `C++` client written. I want to step by step debug the same, but before that I want to start separate server, Can I do the same when I say start debug client. i.e. when visual studio starts client library , it should first my server ( external program )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this, the nicest being [multiple startup projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165413%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). This requires both client and server projects being in the same solution. It allows debugging both exes simultaneously. Using Remote Debug Monitor and altering `Configuration Properties->Debugging` options you can even start the server on a seperate machine.

If you do not want to debug the server project, you can do something like [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498911/run-multiple-instances-with-one-click-in-visual-studio/5539729#5539729)

Another way is to start a batch file in `Configuration Properties->Debugging->Command` and make it start the server first, then the client.