# How do I start a background task from a VisualStudio post-build event?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, background-process, post-build-event

I'm trying to start an instance of [grunt watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) whenever a particular project is run from VisualStudio.  I have a single page-app written in ember, and compiled with grunt, which connects to a backend written with WebAPI. I'm trying to reduce friction so it's possible to Start Debugging (F5) in VS and have it get everything up and going.

If I add a post-build event to compile the app with grunt, it works fine:

```
node node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt dev --no-color
```

`grunt watch` never terminates, so the VisualStudio build appears to hang until you terminate the node.exe process (which is mostly expected, other than not being able to use Ctrl+Break to stop in VS):

```
node ../node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt watch --no-color
```

I've tried starting with the `start` command, but VisualStudio still waits for it to exit (just saying "Build started..."):

```
start node ../node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt dev --no-color
```

I've also tried with start's `/i` parameter, but that doesn't help. It opens a new window running `grunt watch`, but the build doesn't continue (and the app doesn't start) until I close the console window.

[image]

Presumably this has something to do with the process being a child of the build process? Is there an actual way to start a background task without VisualStudio waiting on it?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure why exactly start doesn't do the trick (works perfectly from the command line), but afaik msbuild spawns a seperate cmd process for it's build events so it will have something to do with that.

A working alternative is to use Powershell to start the process instead. No idea about the builtin powershell syntax, but invoking C#'s Process.Start works just as fine:

```
powershell -Command "[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start( '/path/to/node', 'args' )"
```

That answers your question, however I think it's not what you really want, and you're asking the wrong question.. You say you want to 'start an instance whenever a particular project is *run* from VisualStudio', but then you go on asking about build events which occur when a project is *built*. That is different and seems unhandy since every single build will start a new instance. Instead, I think what you actually want/need is to start an instance everytime you start debugging your project. That's also possible as laid out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498911/run-multiple-instances-with-one-click-in-visual-studio/5539729#5539729):

- add an empty project to your solution
- enter your node command under the projects' `Properties->Debugging`
- right-click solution, select `Set Startup Project`
- select `Multiple startup projects`
- set `Action` to `Start` for your main project
- set `Action` to `Start without debugging` for the empty project

Now hit F5 and VS will start node, plus start debugging your project.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "enter your node command under the projects' `properties->Debugging`?

Comment: @JaredBeach the command which starts node, like in the question, something like `node ../node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt watch --no-color`

Comment: Is there a way to get it to close when you stop debugging? Under "Start external program, I have "C:\Windows\System32\java.exe" and under Command line arguments, I have "-jar fakeSMTP-2.0.jar -s". It doesn't close when I stop debugging though

Comment: Nevermind. I switched from a console app project to a winform and that fixed it.... Don't have a clue why