# Execute ng serve when I start IIS debug (VS community)

Tags: angular, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017, angular-cli

I have actually a ASP.NET project with Angular 5 (Angular CLI).

My question is, it is possible to execute ng serve command when i start IIS Express?

Actually I have to open a cmd, execute ng serve and then start IIS.

If someone have a solution for that, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue?

Comment: Just updated your comment

Comment: Hi,something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18472834/how-do-i-%20start-a-background-task-from-a-visualstudio-post-build-event) may get you some help.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to run "ng build" and then deploy files/folders into ISS from "dist" folder of angular cli

Answer (score 2):

1.Just like what adiii4 suggests.
You can call the post-build-event as an alternative way. Copy the ng serve command into the post-build-event textbox.

2.And to achieve this goal: `execute ng serve command when i start IIS Express`

Since we can run [IIS express from command-line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line),you can add the two commands in post-build-event by newlines like [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992536/visual-studio-multiple-post-build-commands).

3.In addition,a post-build-event will run every time you build the project.(No matter debug or release mode)
I'm not sure if this meet your needs well, we can customize it by Right-click Project=>Unload Project=>Edit xxx.csproj.

e.g: We'll find the PostBuild Target at the bottom, add a `Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' "` can help control `only in debug mode` to execute ng serve command and start IIS Express like:

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent"  Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
    <Exec Command="here commad1:call test.exe&#xD;&#xA;here command2:xxx.exe xxx" />
</Target>
```

**Update:**

When we add something in post-build-event, the Target "PostBuild" will be added into xxx.csproj file automatically (Below format is for asp.net core web app).

And we can add a custom script like below to do another target after the build engine run the PostBuild target. For your situation, ngserve.bat is for ng serve, and startIIS.bat is for starting IIS.

```
  <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="call ngserve.bat" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="StartIIS" AfterTargets="PostBuild">
    <Exec Command="call startIIS.bat"/>
  </Target>
```

[image]

**In addition**: In VS, we can `go Tools=>options=>Projects and solutions=>Build and run` to `change the msbuild project build output verbosity` to `detailed`. After that, every time we build the solution or project, we can see detailed info about the build process, which helps troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Im using post-build-event with a bat file but now iis is not starting. I think its because ng serve is never closed and iis is waiting the bat file. Do you know how to start my bat file in background ? Thanks;)

Comment: @Heroz What's the content of the bat file?  Do you mean you use the post-build-event to execute the bat(for ng serve) and then in which way you start the IIS? As a command2 in post-build or start manually?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay and thanks for the help. My bat file contains the command "ng serve". To use it =>  "Right Click on project => Build Event and set "CALL ngServe.bat". After that I run my solution but actually is blocking. Im checking your update

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to utilize the [build events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2019) in Visual Studio.

After a build you could call the command `ng serve` as a post-build event.