# Click once on "Start" to deploy and run on both local and remote machines

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, uwp

I'm testing communication among multiple instances of my UWP by simultaneously running it on both my local machine and a remote machine.  The `Debug` properties in Visual Studio are limiting in that I must choose between either local or remote.  This causes me to perform multiple manual steps whenever I modify the app's code and start a new debugging session.

1. Open the `Debug` properties, where I change from remote to local
2. Build and deploy the solution (locally)
3. Undo that change and start remote debugging
4. Launch the app locally and attach to its process

What a pain!  How can I automate these steps such that I get the same effect just be clicking "Start"?

I tried adding the executable to the solution directly as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39790926), but various errors prevent it from running.  Anyway, that wouldn't help with local deployment.